# can we have like operator with select query as input for it?

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-like

How can I use the `LIKE` operator for a string search and the string is coming as an output of another select statement?

```
SELECT CONCAT('"id":"',transactions.Id,'"')  AS id
FROM transactions.transactions LEFT JOIN
report.PlayerTransaction
ON (transactions.Id=PlayerTransaction.TranId )
WHERE TranId IS  NULL AND  transactions.created_at > '2017-10-15' ;

SELECT *
FROM report.EtlServiceErrorLog 
WHERE Topic = 'player' and  ErrorSourceData like  xxxx and
CreatedDate > '2017-10-15' ;
```

Taking in consideration these 2 queries; I want the query to be written like:

```
SELECT *
FROM report.EtlServiceErrorLog 
WHERE Topic = 'player' and
      ErrorSourceData like in (SELECT CONCAT('"id":"', transactions.Id, '"')  AS id
                               FROM transactions.transactions LEFT JOIN
                                    report.PlayerTransaction
                                    ON (transactions.Id = PlayerTransaction.TranId ) WHERE TranId IS  NULL AND  transactions.created_at > '2017-10-15'
                             ;) and
      CreatedDate > '2017-10-15' ;
```

Or do I have to get help of looping for it? Please provide me an example.

Comment: Why `LIKE`? I see no wildcard in `CONCAT('"id":"',transactions.Id,'"')`. `LIKE` is for pattern matching, e.g. `col LIKE 'ABC%'`. `col LIKE 'ABC'` in comparision makes little sense and we would rather write `col = 'ABC'`.

Comment: ErrorSourceData contains huge json data stored as string and that is the reason like been used there

Answer (score 1):

It seems you really want to look for

```
ErrorSourceData LIKE CONCAT('%"id":"', t.Id, '"%')
```

This cannot be done with `IN`. You need `EXISTS`.

```
SELECT *
FROM report.EtlServiceErrorLog sel
WHERE Topic = 'player' 
AND EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM transactions.transactions t
  WHERE t.id NOT IN (SELECT pt.TranId FROM report.PlayerTransaction pt)
  AND t.created_at > '2017-10-15'
  AND sel.ErrorSourceData LIKE CONCAT('%"id":"', t.Id, '"%')
)
AND CreatedDate > '2017-10-15' ;
```

Comment: I thought this is what  i was looking for but the query does not return result even after running for an hour !!!

Comment: I suppose you could check, if this query does what you need by limiting the result set, i.e. by adding criteria like `and sel.report_id in (1,2,3,4,5)`. If the result is fine, then only speed is the problem. With multiple `like '%something%'` it is hard to speed this up, though. Do all EtlServiceErrorLog records contain `'%"id":"'`? If not, then you could add this criteria `and sel.ErrorSourceData like '%"id":"%'` and hope the subquery gets called less often. An index on `transactions(created_at, id)` should help. (I take it for granted that you have foreign key constraints on the IDs, too.)

Answer (score 0):

It will work provided sub query returns just 1 row.

Comment: sub querry doesnt return 1 row..it returns many rows and i want my like operator to check in all of those

Answer (score 0):

IF u dont use  LIKE Operator '%'  _ change to  IN
ErrorSourceData in(SELECT CONCAT('"id":"', transactions.Id, '"')